# Cloud Foundry Java Startup Command

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

When running a Java application in Cloud Foundry, based on the Java Buildpack, I would like to see the java command line that started the Tomcat server to see the specific memory parameters set on the JVM. Is there a way to see the specific command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run

```
cf curl /v2/apps/`cf app <YOUR-APP-NAME> -—guid`| grep detected_start_command
```

Comment: I had to meake a small change due to a cut/paste error. The "--guid" didn't come across cleanly.